# loading <tbody> using ajax without loading whole table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table like this

```
<table>
<thead>
      <tr>
           <td>col_1</td><td>col_2</td><td>col_3</td>
      </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="content">
      <tr>
           <td>cell_1_1</td><td>cell_1_2</td><td>cell_1_3</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button id="ref" value="Refresh" />
```

I want to load only content of `<tbody>` using ajax.
and this is my script

```
$("ref").click(function(){
$.post("ajax.php",
function(data)
{
    $("#content").html(data)    
})
});
```

and the ajax.php file is like this

```
echo ' <tr>
           <td>cell_1_1</td><td>cell_1_2</td><td>cell_1_3</td>
       </tr>';
```

but when I load it ,loaded data lose their style as table "tr"s and "td"s.
I know whats wrong whit it ,and when I load it as a complete "table" it works.
but, Is there any idea for loading `<tbody>` separately ???

Comment: What do you mean by `lose their style as table trs and tds`? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I mean these are only texts and it isn't cells of tables .
like I don't use any <tr> and <td>.

Comment: Is it possible that the server returns the data html-encoded? can you check the raw response?

Comment: Check if some tag is not closing properly

Comment: You've done something wrong, though I'm not entirely sure what. I load sections of tables all the time and I've never had issues with them not displaying correctly.

Comment: thanks alot friends.
I checked again what you said
as I said when I load a complete table it works
but I can't load content of tbody

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend the use of `$.ajax` for this because it is much more customizable:

```
$("ref").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php', // URL of where AJAX should POST the data
        type: 'POST', // Send a POST to server
        data: {'id': 3243}, // Data to be POSTED to server. In PHP use echo $_POST['id']; to see what the AJAX passed in
        dataType: 'HTML', // Expected data from server
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); // <-- view what the server sent back to AJAX
            // OR
            alert(data);  // <-- view what the server sent back to AJAX

            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

I still recommend using AJAX but after reading through the comments some more I have a question:

Are you using jQuery to format the table after initial load like this?

```
$('table tbody tr td').css({'padding':'10px'});
```

Because if yes then you need to repeat it after `$("#content").html(data);` like this:

```
$("#content").html(data);
$('table tbody tr td').css({'padding':'10px'});
```

The reason for this is because `.css()` styles elements at an inline level so when you refresh the HTML() then those `<td>`'s lose their styles. You should declare the styling in your CSS file to make sure it doesn't get lost upon refresh.